# How to show hidden ul when checkbox is checked using css?

Tags: html, css

I have these elements :

```
<label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Organizations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Take Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resourses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css :

```
.tabs{display:none}

#toggle:checked+ .tabs{
        display:block
}
```

I also tried :

```
#toggle:checked~ .tabs{
    display:block
}
```

But it still doesn't show up the hidden `<ul class="tabs">`

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused **by a problem** that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @Paulie_D , I haven't got my problem solved yet

Comment: @Paulie_D , Thanks , You can close it now

Answer (score 1):

Target your input instead.

```css
.tabs {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .tabs{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Organizations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Take Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resourses</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.tabs{
    display:none
}

#toggle:checked + .tabs{
    display:block
}
```

The spacing makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
.tabs {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + .tabs {
  display: block;
}
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

*Because demo snippets cannot be inserted into comments...*

**Your code works , test snippets below**:

- CSS

```css
#toggle:checked + .tabs{
   display:block
}
```

```css
.tabs{display:none}

#toggle:checked + .tabs{
        display:block
}
```

```html
<label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Organizations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Take Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resourses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

- CSS

```css
#toggle:checked ~ .tabs{
   display:block
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  display: none
}

#toggle:checked~.tabs {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Organizations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Take Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resourses</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your problem stands else where :( **Please clarify question with bits of codes that actually shows your issue.**